# Synchronous OCR with Azure Cognitive Services without Additional API Calls

Tags: python, azure, asynchronous, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently using Azure Cognitive Services for optical character recognition (OCR) on images. I've implemented the OCR functionality using both synchronous and asynchronous methods provided by the Azure Python SDK. However, I'm concerned about the cost and the need for periodic API calls when using the asynchronous method.

The asynchronous method involves calling read to initiate the OCR operation and then polling get_read_result until the operation is complete. **While this approach works, it requires periodic calls to get_read_result, which I've learned can add to the cost as each call incurs charges**.

On the other hand, the synchronous method using recognize_printed_text provides results without the need for additional API calls. However, **I've noticed that the accuracy and quality of the synchronous OCR results are weaker compared to the asynchronous method**.

I'm seeking advice on whether there's a way to perform OCR synchronously with Azure Cognitive Services without making additional API calls for result retrieval. Additionally, I'm open to suggestions on improving the accuracy of the synchronous OCR results or alternative approaches to minimize costs while maintaining accuracy.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**asynchronous method**

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import OperationStatusCodes
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

import time

'''
References:
    Quickstart: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/python-sdk
    SDK: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/cognitiveservices/computervision?view=azure-python
'''

# Replace with your endpoint and key from the Azure portal
endpoint = 'https://....cognitiveservices.azure.com/'
key = '....'

# Set credentials
credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(key)

# Create client
client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, credentials)

url = "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/dcYAAOSw~5NlHSbh/s-l960.jpg"

raw = True
custom_headers = None
numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36
rawHttpResponse = client.read(url, language="en", raw=True)

# Get ID from returned headers
operationLocation = rawHttpResponse.headers["Operation-Location"]
idLocation = len(operationLocation) - numberOfCharsInOperationId
operationId = operationLocation[idLocation:]

# SDK call
#this is ASYNC!!! need to wait!!
#else returns empty!
while True:
    result = client.get_read_result(operationId)
    print(f"result: {result}")
    if result.status not in ['notStarted', 'running']:
        print("breaking")
        break
    time.sleep(1)


# Get data: displays text captured and its bounding box (position in the image)
if result.status == OperationStatusCodes.succeeded:
    for line in result.analyze_result.read_results[0].lines:
        print(line.text)
        #print(line.bounding_box)
```

**synchronous method**

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials


# Replace with your endpoint and key from the Azure portal
endpoint = 'https://....cognitiveservices.azure.com/'
key = ' '

# Set credentials
credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(key)

# Create client
client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, credentials)

url = "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/dcYAAOSw~5NlHSbh/s-l960.jpg"

language = "en"

# SDK call - Synchronous OCR
result = client.recognize_printed_text(url, language=language)

# Get data: displays text captured and its bounding box (position in the image)
for region in result.regions:
    for line in region.lines:
        words = [word.text for word in line.words]
        print(' '.join(words))
        # print(line.bounding_box)
```

Comment: Those are different operations, not the synchronous and asynchronous version of the same operation. It makes sense that the more accurate method will be slower. `add to the cost as each call incurs charges.` how much and is it worth even asking? The batch operation may be (relatively) expensive, but a status check may cost $1 per 1M requests

Comment: The [pricing docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) mention `Read` prices, not checking the status. They do mention that [get_read_status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/how-to/call-read-api#get-results-from-the-service) has a rate limit, not extra cost

Comment: Ty, what you write is quite reasonable. But on the document i can't see any statement about get result cost nor saying it is free? Maybe best to ask Azure support directly